# Azure Logic App is timing out on Response despite executing in less than 10 seconds

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have a logic app with an HTTP trigger and ends with a Response.  99% of the time the logic app successfully executes, however ocassionaly I am getting a timeout error even though the total execution time of the app is less than 10 seconds.

Here's a snippet of the logic app Runs History:

[image: Run history]

For the failed run, I am receiving this message on the Response step:

*ActionResponseTimedOut. The execution of template action 'Response' is failed: the client application timed out waiting for a response from service. This means that workflow took longer to respond than the alloted timeout value. The connection maintained between the client application and service will be closed and client application will get an HTTP status code 504 Gateway Timeout.*

[image: Logic app steps]

The logic app is executed via a request through APIM. Any ideas on why this is timing out would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any funny logs on the APIM side?

Comment: Hi @Skin Yes, I have just checked the app insights and there is an error on the API: "Client connection was unexpectedly closed." with a response code "0 [not sent in full". Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth raising it with Microsoft directly.